# Qt executable running in release folder - Runtime error in Program Files (x86)

Tags: c++, sql, qt, sqlite, runtime-error

I seem to be getting a runtime error when trying to run my Qt application.

I am able to successfully build my application in release mode and it runs just fine sitting in the release folder. That's not where it's going to sit when users install it, however. I need it to run in `C:/Program Files (x86)/ApplicationName/application.exe`.

So I moved the application there. I recently added some `SQLite` functionality to the application. So I expected to get some sort of missing dll file error. I did. So I found the correct dll file (`Qt5Sql.dll`) and moved it into that directory. Now I'm getting a Runtime Error.

To figure out what was causing this Runtime Error, I threw in a bunch of `QMessageBox::warning`s to see when it was getting the error. The error is being caused by this line of code:

```
sqlite = new SQLite(QString("%1%2").arg(myDocuments).arg(SQLite::DATABASE_NAME));
```

I checked to make sure I was getting the expected `QString` from `QString("%1%2").arg(myDocuments).arg(SQLite::DATABASE_NAME)` and I was.

Here is what that constructor looks like in `sqlite.cpp`:

```
SQLite::SQLite(const QString& path)
{
    database = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    database.setDatabaseName(path);

    if (!database.open())
    {
        QMessageBox::warning(NULL, "Error", "Failed to open database.");
    }
}
```

The peculiar thing is I know I'm not even getting into that constructor because I put a `QMessageBox::warning` before the first line in the constructor and I'm not seeing that before the Runtime Error. I am seeing the `QMessageBox::warning` directly before the constructor though.

Anyone out there have any idea what might be causing this?

Edit:

I believe I was missing the `sqldriver` folder which included the `qsqlite.dll`. I added that folder to where my `exe` file is, but I'm still getting a runtime error. I added the following to my code for debugging purposes:

```
QStringList drivers = QSqlDatabase::drivers();
QString ds;
int len = drivers.length();
for (int x = 0; x < len; x++)
{
    ds.append(QString("%1\n").arg(drivers[x]));
}
QMessageBox::warning(this, "DRIVERS", ds);
sqlite = new SQLite(QString("%1%2").arg(myDocuments).arg(SQLite::DATABASE_NAME));
```

The `QMessageBox` shows:

```
QSQLITE
QODBC
QODBC3
QPSQL
QPSQL7
```

After I click OK on the dialog, however, I am still getting the runtime error. Despite the `QSQLITE` driver clearly being available, I'm getting the runtime error on this line of code:

```
QSqlDatabase database = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
```

Comment: `Qt5Sql.dll` is the generic sql library. you still need the sqlite plugin library in path too. This is resolved at runtime. Not sure about the paths, where is it searched.

Comment: I was thinking I might need something like that for sqlite specifically. But where the heck is that? I don't see any `Qt5Sqlite.dll` or anything like that.

Comment: You need to put the `sqldrivers` folder  from the `<qtdir>\plugins` near you `application.exe`. This is the usual rule for all plugins.

Comment: @VladimirBershov Seems legit, but where exactly do I put those relative to the `application.exe`?

Comment: The folder `sqldrivers` should be located **near** the executable file, 
in the same directory as your program `application.exe` is.

Comment: I dropped all the `dll` files in the `sqldrivers` directory where the `exe` was. That did not work. I copied the `sqldrivers` folder containing the `dll` files where the `exe` was. That did not work. I dropped `plugins` which included the `sqldrivers` folder into the directory where the `exe` was. That did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much hair pulling I figured out the issue. It seems one of the `Qt5*` dlls I was using was outdated. I saw this error when I moved the dll files from `C:/Program Files...` to my release folder and tried running a release version from `QtCreator`:

```
Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (version 0x50100) with this library (version 0x50101)
```

After seeing this, I updated all the `Qt5*` dll files in my `C:/Program Files (x86)/ApplicationName/` directory and that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

To simplify your life, if you have a recent version of Qt 5, you can use [windeployqt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html#the-windows-deployment-tool) on your application to get the dependencies pulled at the correct place.